# Intent to View Calendar for particular instance of event

Tags: android, android-calendar

I've got a trigger to try to open a particular event in the user's Calendar application. The problem here is with recurring events (somewhat as expected) - it opens up the **event**, and not the event instance.

I don't have the query up here, but I'm hitting the Instances table for the Event ID, Start Time, and End Time.

```
public class CalendarItem {

    long eventID;
    long startTime;
    long endTime;

    public CalendarItem (long eventID, long startTime, long endTime) {
            this.eventID = eventID;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public void openCalendarWithIntent(){
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
            Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(uri);
            //calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
            //calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
            calIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(calIntent);
    }
}
```

With any event, the calendar will open up to the first instance of that event. If I add in the extra flags (begin time and end time), it opens up to that "event" with that start time and end time, which is better, but still not actually the instance I'm looking for.

Is there any way to open up to a SPECIFIC event instance?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, there was an error in my earlier logic that had the "endTime" set incorrectly.

You can open to a specific instance ***as long as*** both the EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME and EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME match an instance EXACTLY.

Comment: so what is exactly solution? I used your openCalendarWithIntent() method above, uncommented and filled start/end times, and it still does not work...

Comment: Make sure that the type of both EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME and EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME is a Long.